# PHP execution timing out after update

Tags: php, apache, error-handling

Needed Finfo but deleted msi package, so uninstalled php 5.3.0, downloaded 5.3.2 and installed. Now all my sites have max execution time error's when they hit my custom error handlers. No problems until I updated - has anyone ran into this before?

Checked all error logs and ran through config files - nothing stands out.

**Edit:**

Commented error handler and I get:

> Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not (trying to connect via
>   tcp://localhost:3306) in ...Core.php 
>   on line 60

Lines 59-60 of core.php:

```
$this->db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $config['database']['db'],
        $config['login']['username'], $config['login']['password']);
```

PDO is connecting to MySQL 5. I'm starting to think this may be a 5.3.2 bug.

Comment: Can you show your custom error handler?

Comment: It would still be interesting to see your error handler.

Comment: I'm not posting my error handler because it has no link whatsoever with this problem. If you're curious, it errored originally when parsing 'function errorhandler($errNo, $errStr, $errFile, $errLine) {', but the entire file has since been commented out.

Comment: What in the world are you connected to? What are you passing into the PDO? Can you ping the object you are connecting to (a database I assume)?

Comment: @Danten: If the file is commented out and the system still fails, then the problem doesn't lie in the error handler. If the error handler really is the cause, nobody here is going to be able to be much of a help. It's entirely possible that the bug lies somewhere in your code but the bug wasn't "tickled" until it was run on the new runtime. It's also entirely possible the bug likes in 5.3.2. But without code nobody can tell.

Comment: That's a possibility Billy, I'll take a look. MySQL server is operating fine from a terminal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved by re-installing PHP 5.3.0. Possible 5.3.2 bug or a bug from my own code triggered by update.